# Find common parent of first,second,and third "p" element and if it is only 3 levels up using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

suppose

```
<body>
 <div class="common-parent">
    <div class="level-1">
          <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="level-1">
          <div class-"level-2">
          <p>more text</p>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="level-1">
          <div class="level-2">
              <div class="level-3">
               <p>even more text</p>
               </div>
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Considering this, the p element with "text" and "more text"  would be selected. But the p element "even more text" would not be because it is nested further than 3 levels.

Comment: What jQuery Code you have written so far>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
//slides the element with class "menu_body" when paragraph with class "menu_head" is clicked 
    $(".common-parent .level-1 p ").each(function()
    {
         /*Code to implement */
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with multiple selectors:

```
var $nodes = $(".level-1>p, .level-2>p");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the 'level' classes set on your divs. You can do it all via direct descendent `>` selectors like this:

```
$("#common-parent>div>p, #common-parent>div>div>p");
```